# Why Gnocchi apply 'server_group' to resource slowly?

Tags: openstack

I add the metadata `"metering.server_group":"corey-group"` to an instance while creating, and check it by using `nova show`, it is applied, then I check the Gnocchi resource using `gnocchi resource show --type instance ${instance-id}`, the attribute `server_group` is `None` in the begining, but after a while, it will be applied (always on the hour, ex: 07:00, 08:00...), I have no idea what happens, I think this issue will cause Gnocchi gets incorrect datasets while doing aggregation, so I spent some times to troubleshoot it.

First of all, the attributes of Gnocchi resource stored in database:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> use gnocchi
MariaDB [gnocchi]> select * from resource_type where name='instance';
# check its tablename, ex: rt_xxxxxx
MariaDB [gnocchi]> select * from rt_xxxxxx where display_name='corey-vm';

+----------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---+
| display_name   | host                | image_ref | flavor_id                            | server_group | id             | flavor_name  |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---+
| corey-vm       | corey-test-com-001  | NULL      | 26e46b4c-23bd-4224-a609-29bd3094a18e | NULL         | xxxxxx         | corey-flavor |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---+
```

As you can see, the column `server_group` should be `corey-group`, but it is always `NULL` when the instance is just created, and seems like ceilometer updates the resource per hour **on the hour**.

I added some log in the file [ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py](https://github.com/openstack/ceilometer/blob/master/ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py#L451), and found that it updates resource every minutes, but the variable `resource_extra` gets `server_group` only **on the hour**, that's why it is None is the begining.

Here are some parts of the logs

> 2020-11-09 **11:59:15** DEBUG ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi Resource {'host': u'test-com-002', 'display_name': u'vm-001', 'flavor_id': u'xxx', 'flavor_name': u'xxx'} publish_samples /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py:345

> 2020-11-09 **12:00:15** DEBUG ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi Resource {'host': u'test-com-002', 'display_name': u'vm-001', 'flavor_name': u'xxx', **'server_group': 'corey-group'**} publish_samples /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py:345

> 2020-11-09 **12:01:15** DEBUG ceilometer.publisher.gnocchi Resource {'host': u'test-com-002', 'display_name': u'vm-001', 'flavor_id': u'xxx', 'flavor_name': u'xxx'} publish_samples /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceilometer/publisher/gnocchi.py:345

But I stuck at this point, I can't understand why the variable `resource_extra` can't gets `server_group` each time. What causes this happpening exactly? (Running on Queens)

I would appreciate any ideas.

**Update 09/11/2020**

After some days of troubleshooting, I still can't find the root cause.

But I found a command line to apply the 'server_group' manually, that can help me to avoid Gnocchi gets incorrect datasets to aggregate.

Here it is:

```
gnocchi resource update --type instance -a server_group:corey-group ${resource_id}
```

**Update 11/11/2020**

I tried to `grep` the integer 3600 and modify them to 300, but nothing changed, below are what I've tried.

/etc/ceilometer/ceilometer.conf

```
[compute]
resource_cache_expiry = 300
```

ceilometer/compute/discovery.py

```
cfg.IntOpt('resource_cache_expiry',
            default=300,
```

ceilometer/publisher/zaqar.py

```
DEFAULT_TTL = 300
```

**Update 12/11/2020**

I can't reproduce this issue on Pike.

Comment: Ceilometer can have different intervals for different metrics. These are defined in the `polling.yaml` and `pipeline.yaml` of your ceilometer. Do you already checked these files? Maybe you have to define `server_group` explicit there to have the same update-interval, like the other metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, but I have no idea how to explicitly define `server_group` in those config files, seems it is not a metric.

Comment: I tried to update the value of `resource_cache_expiry` from 3600 to 300 in `ceilometer.conf`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can refer to the following discussions:

[Heat autoscaling with gnocchi based aodh alarms requires use of naive instance_discovery_method setting with ceilometer compute agents?](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-ceilometer-agent/+bug/1749954)

According to the reference, try to change the default `instance_discovery_method` from "libvirt_metadata" to **"naive"** in ceilometer config file, like this:

```
[compute]
instance_discovery_method = naive
```

Switching to "naive" resolves this issue, however it obviously generates load on the Nova API for metadata retrieval.